# Android change distance dynamically on the screen - for now changes only when orientation change

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localization, gps

I have a problem and cannot find an answer for that.

Code:

In Activity SetGeographicCoordinatesActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_geograpic_coordinates);
        destinationLatitude = findViewById(R.id.destinationLatitude);
        destinationLongitude = findViewById(R.id.destinationLongitude);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        destinationLocation = new Location("Destination");

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            setGeoCords();
        });
    }

    private void setGeoCords() {
        float destinationLat = Float.parseFloat(destinationLatitude.getText().toString());
        float destinationLon = Float.parseFloat(destinationLongitude.getText().toString());
        destinationLocation.setLatitude(destinationLat);
        destinationLocation.setLongitude(destinationLon);
        setDestinationLocation(destinationLocation);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewCompass);
        destinationDistance = findViewById(R.id.destinationDistance);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            openSetGeographicCoordinatesActivity();
        });

        locationFetcher = new LocationFetcher(this);
        locationFetcher.connectGps();
        locationFetcher.onLocationChanged(location);

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        permissionCheckAFL = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissionCheckACL = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        permissionCheck();
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
            if (location != null) {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
            Location destinationLocation;
            destinationLocation = SetGeographicCoordinatesActivity.getDestinationLocation();
            distance = location.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
            updateTextView(distance);
        }
        });
    }
```

```
 private void openSetGeographicCoordinatesActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetGeographicCoordinatesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

private void permissionCheck() {
        int REQUEST_CODE = 102;
        if(permissionCheckAFL != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheckACL != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

private void updateTextView(final float distance) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                destinationDistance.setText("Distance from the destination: " + Float.toString(distance) + "m");
                destinationDistance.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }
```

User type latitude and longitude in first activity - a destination. Then app have to get user location and show how many meters away he is from destination and update this distance when he is moving.

I want to achieve TextView updating every second or atleast updating automatically without user action. Any tips what am I doing wrong?